# discord bot that replies to people with specific roles python

Tags: discord.py

I have a bot that currently does nothing other than keep itself hosted online

I have tried finding an answer to this but everything is for Javascript

basically what I'm looking for is a bot that:

When someone sends a message detect if he has role "X"
If he has role "X" reply with a prewritten message

for example, if someone has a role named "PlaysROR2"
whenever he types the word game the bot will send the message ROR2

I'm new to making discord bots and python in general so the more specific the answer the better
from what I understood there's no Has_role function so it's pretty complicated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="PlaysROR2")
    if role in message.author.roles and message.content == "game":
        await message.channel.send("ROR2")
    else:
        return
```

Try this? I'm not very good at discord.py, sorry, and I haven't tested this yet so it might not work.

Comment: Also, remember to include `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end inside it if you have [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?). Otherwise, your commands won't work. [From documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)